# Java program shutdown on Linux

Tags: java, linux, netty, daemon

I am running a java server program on Linux in a virtual instance (from provider). It is a complex program based on Netty. I start it using:

```
nohup java -jar server.jar > server.txt
```

Then, it works fine. But sometimes, it crashes - around 1 time in a week (there is no more process listening on the port). When I read logs, and `server.txt`, there is nothing in there. No exception detected, or log information. But the program shuts down. What can be the reason for such a behaviour? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run your code like this:

```
nohup java -jar server.jar >server.txt 2>&1
```

This will log any errors produced and you can add them here for help or figure out on your own.